# Python priting path with strange characters

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, path

I'm using a script which runs with Python 3.4 and the selenium library, and I'm getting this error

> PhantomJS with Selenium error: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs
>   to be in PATH

which has a solution here

[PhantomJS with Selenium error: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903536/phantomjs-with-selenium-error-message-phantomjs-executable-needs-to-be-in-pa)

but when I try to implement the solution the path to C:\DriverPath\Bin\ is wrongly brought, when I print the property which has it (self.path), it prints

[image]

with that dot over there instead of C:\DriverPath\Bin\ and it keeps triggering "PhantomJS with Selenium error: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH" . Any idea what could it be

Comment: I assume, this is window's way of rendering `\b`. When setting paths in python, either escape backslashes (i.e. `"C:\\DriverPath\\Bin\\"`) or use raw strings (i.e. `r"C:\DriverPath\Bin\"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Selenium 3.4.3 & PhantomJS 2.1.1 with Python 3.6.1 the following lines of code initializes the PhantomJS Driver perfecto:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.