# PhantomJS with Selenium: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I having trouble installing PhantomJS to my project
Following the suggestions from the similar question from so I defined the `$PATH` variable with executable path

```
cd Users/zkid18/project/venv/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/phantomjs-2.1.1/bin 
export PATH=$PWD
```

Then I try to create a driver with a virtual browser

```
import from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

On this step I got an error

```
No such file or directory: 'phantomjs': 'phantomjs'
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Check whether you've downloaded 32-bit PhantomJS version for 32-bit OS or 64-bit version for 64-bit OS... Also it's better to append directory to PATH (`export PATH=$PATH:$PWD`) instead of re-define PATH...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhantomJS with Selenium error: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903536/phantomjs-with-selenium-error-message-phantomjs-executable-needs-to-be-in-pa)

Comment: `export PATH=$PWD` will likely make your shell unusable.

Comment: @Andersson I use mac os x, so I guess only one version availbale

Comment: Check my answer, It works for both windows and mac os.

Comment: Check this answer.
This will work fine
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64437609/12017533

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the path:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='Complete path/to/phantomjs')
```

To find it use `export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}` in the command line as @Anderson commented.

Comment: If this is a dup, please post it as a dup (it looks like you already did) and then don't answer because it causes confusion to new (and potentially other) users.

Comment: @JeffC I did but it looks like it doesn't answer OP's question... take a look at the flag I raised

Comment: @MosheSlavin I'm a bit confused about using defining PATH properly. Why should I append path instead of redefining it? 
After `export PATH=$PATH:$PWD` I run `$PATH` in the command line
bash: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/zkid18/project/venv/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/phantomjs-2.1.1/bin: No such file or directory`
Seems I did something wrong

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
No such file or directory: 'phantomjs': 'phantomjs'
```

...implies that the program was unable to locate the **phantomjs** binary.

As you are on *MAC OS X* you need to download **phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip** from [Download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) page and extract (unzip) the content within your system. Next you can mention the *absolute path* of **phantomjs** binary passing the argument `executable_path` as follows:

- *MAC OS X* example:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/path/to/phantomjs-2.1.1-xxx/bin/phantomjs')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- *Windows OS* example:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```